# Sharing a Geoprocessing Service Hangs on Publishing service

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service

When I tried publishing a geoprocessing service as part of a [tutorial from ESRI](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0057000000mr000000), the Service Editor in ArcCatalog hung on the following screen:

[image: Screenshot of the Service Editor]

That being said, the service seems to act OK. I can browse to its page via ArcGIS Server without any trouble.

What should I do to properly publish the service?

Comment: I would say it is fine.  I have experienced several times this week the same thing. (Either hanging or taking a long time).